# How to replace lines depending on the remaining text in file using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to edit txt file using PowerShell. The problem is that I need to apply changes for the string only if the remaining part of the string matches some pattern. For example, I need to change '***specific_text***' to '***other_text***' only if the line ends with '***pattern***':

```
'specific_text and pattern' -> changes to 'other_text and pattern'
```

But if the line doesn't end with ***pattern***, I don't need to change it:

```
'specific_text and something else' -> no changes
```

I know about Replace function in PowerShell, but as far as I know it makes simple change for all matches of the regex. There is also Select-String function, but I couldn't combine them properly. My idea was to make it this way:

```
((get-content myfile.txt | select-string -pattern "pattern") -Replace "specific_text", "other_text") | Out-File myfile.txt
```

But this call rewrites the whole file and leaves only changed lines.

Comment: `-Replace "specific_text(?=.*pattern$)", "other_text"`

Comment: Thank you, @WiktorStribiżew! If you want, you can write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(get-content myfile.txt) -replace 'specific_text(?=.*pattern$)', "other_text" | Out-File myfile.txt
```

The `specific_text(?=.*pattern$)` pattern matches

- `specific_text` - some `specific_text`...
- `(?=.*pattern$)` - not immediately followed with any 0 or more chars other than a newline as many as possible and then `pattern` at the end of the string (`$`).